# Election page sidebar current choices are... misplaced

Tags: bug, election

When scrolling further than your current election choices in the sidebar on [the election page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election), the block of choices gets a `position: fixed;` added to it... I assume it is meant to be "sticky" and stick to the top of the screen... there is no explicit `top` or `bottom` applied though so it actually gets stuck ~ 1000px from the top... That means it's invisible if your browser window isn't as tall as that (which is probably most users), otherwise you see this:

> [image]

It's stuck, half obscured, to the bottom of the screen. It also has no background (it's in a white container when it's static in the sidebar) so it makes a bit of a mess over the footer.

Reproduced on the most recent Chrome, Firefox and Safari on macOS.

Comment: no error here OS X 10.11.3 on Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). Worked fine at my office too on Firefox on Windows (not sure version off hand)

Comment: No error here Win 10 Chrome 58 (64 bit)

Comment: @Ryan no error as in it *is* sticky as it's supposed to be or you just don't see it at all?

Comment: cc @ZachSaucier ^

Comment: It has `position: relative;`, not sticky or fixed for me

Comment: hmm that is strange

Comment: Although on Firefox they disappear after the top of the container is scrolled by. It goes to `fixed` but is below the screen position. Something is definitely off

Comment: @Zach yeh that's what I'm talking about... it's only below your screen position if your browser window is less than ~1000px high (you can zoom out to see it if you can't get your window big enough)

Comment: I'm guessing it's doing some failed script based on feature detection

Comment: Reproduced in Opera 45.0 and Chrome 58.0 on WIndows10

Comment: Hey @Cai, I didn't know I was your first choice (*blushing*)... :P